# Finite equivalent to integration

Tags: integration

The finite equivalent to derivation is called finite differences:

> $$
> \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(x+h)-(x)} \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad f(x+h)-f(x)
> $$

What's the equivalent definition for integration?

> $$
> \int_{[a,b]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad \color{red}{?}
> $$

At first I thought $\sum_{i=a}^b  f(x_i)$, but this doesn't account for uneven steps, and although $h=1$ seems natural, there seems to be no reason to exclude $h\neq 1$, so how would the fundamental theorem of *finite* calculus compare?

Comment: You could also see Knuth, Graham, Patashnik’s *Concrete mathematics*, §2.6 *Finite and infinite calculus*. There is a pretty comprehensive collection of facts and analogies of discrete and continuous calculi. There, although, $h = 1$, but you could alleviate this by scaling functions before and after performing ‘$h = 1$’-operations.

Answer (score 4):

It's one you probably already knew. The Riemann sum that is used to define the Riemann integral:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i^*)\Delta x_i$$
where $\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$ and $x_i^*\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$.

Comment: That seems right, except there's no reference to the interval $[a,b]$ using that notation. The points $x_i^*$ are also not equidistant.

Comment: Right, I meant the Riemann integral over the interval $[x_0,x_n]$ and it should indeed be interpreted as *a* Riemann sum due to the free choice of the $x_i^*\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ (I used *the* to denote the concept). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the discrete analogue of continuous integral then this is what we call quadrature formulas or numerical integration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

The most basic one is the mean of the values of the function over an equidistribution of points in the interval $[a,b]$ (this amounts to approximating the graph of the function by a sequence of rectangles). Quadrature formulas get more complicated when we wish to have better precision: there are quadrature formulas which are exact for polynomials up to degree $k$, etc.

If you want to know more start with the Wikipedia page where already some basic examples are shown.